# Assignment operator returning NaN

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to keep track of the time while using window.requestAnimationFrame() but the += operator keeps returning NaN even though the value I'm incrementing by isn't NaN

```
var elapsedTime = 0
var lastTime = 0
var between = 500
var count = 0
var betweenCount = 0
function frame(time) {
    elapsedTime = time - lastTime
    console.log(elapsedTime)
    lastTime = time
    betweenCount += elapsedTime
    console.log(betweenCount)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frame)
}

frame()
```

betweenCount should be keeping track of the total elapsed time since its last reset, but it becomes NaN as soon as elapsedTime is assigned to it, but elapsed time isn't NaN at that point.

Comment: That's because you do not pass an argument when you call  `frame` the first time. Better turn that call into `window.requestAnimationFrame(frame)` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're calling `frame()` without any arguments the first time, `time` will be `undefined` in the function, `elapsedTime` will become `undefined - lastTime` which is `NaN`.

You need to give the initial `frame()` call a valid argument, e.g. `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you don't passing any parameters value while calling a function, So at that time it's `undefined`and you try to upgrade value with`+ operator`,  `+ operator` works on numbers, In your case you try to increment some value so it's first try to convert string to number and suddenly it thrown an error `NaN`;

```js
const a = 'string';
console.log(+a) ; // NaN
```